# Repeating the testing/training split while performing cross-validation on rf model

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm fitting random forest regressions on my data, and using 10 K-fold cross-validation to evaluate model performance. While re-runing the cross-validation, I noticed that the results differed between each run, sometimes by a lot. So, I decided to repeat the cross-validation calculation 20 times, creating a for-loop, and then summarising the results afterwards. Just to illustrate, I'm doing something like this:

```
for (i in 1:20) {

trainIndex <- createDataPartition(data$response, p = .8, list = FALSE, times = 1)
data_train <- data[ trainIndex,]
data_test  <- data[-trainIndex,]

train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", 
                              number = 10)

model <- train(formula, data = data_train, method = "rf",
               trControl = train.control)


pred <- predict(model, data_test)
t<- postResample(pred = pred, obs = data_test$estimate)
t <- t[[2]]

result[[i]] <- t }
```

So, essentially, each re-run I am splitting my dataset into training and testing sets again. This results in a lot of variance, when ploting the resuls of each run together they vary from ~`0.2` to `0.6` `R.squared`. If I don't do this within the loop (i.e. if I split into training/testing before the loop), then the results of the 20 runs are very similar.

Which way is the right way to go about this?

Comment: Random forests are notorious for overfitting (I would almost never use them).  Don't use training/test splits, which requires an enormous sample size for both samples.  Instead repeat 10-fold cross-validation 100 times to get precise estimates of model performance.  But when you see that much variation in RF from resample to resample you should start questioning its use.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we split the train/test at each experiment to reflect the model's sensitivity to slightly changing data. Also, your algorithm may not always have randomness inside, e.g. linear regression (except the gradient descent part), which means repeated experiments you'll perform have little value.